# Presenting modal in iOS 13 with custom height

Tags: objective-c, iphone, user-interface, ios13

In iOS 13 there is a new behaviour for modal view controller when being presented.And I found the build-in App Photo presents a smaller model view controller.

How can I present a viewController with a custom size like this，and can slide up to a larger height?

[image: smaller height]

[image: larger height]

Picture screenshots from system photo app.

Comment: @AshishKakkad. It isn't a same issue. My problem is focused on the viewController height.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is possible Presenting modal in iOS 13 with custom height.
You just need to add the below code into your Presenting modal

```
 override func updateViewConstraints() {
        self.view.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 150
        self.view.frame.origin.y =  150
        self.view.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10.0)
        super.updateViewConstraints()
 }

 extension UIView {
   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

**Answer in Swift**

I was looking for a way to replicate that type of ViewController behaviour, albeit with basic UI and have found a rather simple solution.
Basically, you create a ViewController (`CardViewContoller`) with a transparent background and then add to it a card-like view with a `UIPanGestureReconizer`, that will enable you to drag it around and dismiss it with the ViewController.

To present you simply call `present`, setting the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.overCurrentContext` and `modalTransitionStyle` to `.coverVertical`:

```
let cardVC = CardViewController()
cardVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
cardVC.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
present(cardVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The in `CardViewController`, which can be created programmatically or using Interface Builder, you add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your card view (`contentView`):

```
let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss(recognizer:)))
panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
contentView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
```

Then just add an `@objc` function that will respond to the UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
    @objc
    func handleDismiss (recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .changed:
            viewTranslation = recognizer.translation(in: view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                guard self.viewTranslation.y > 0 else {return}
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.viewTranslation.y)
            })
        case .ended:
            if viewTranslation.y < swipeThreshold {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.transform = .identity
                })
            } else {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

The `swipeThreshold` is a `CGFloat` variable with a value of your choosing (*200 works great for me*), that if the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` y translation exceeds, will trigger the dismissal of the ViewController along with all the elements.
Likewise, you can add a simple button that will dismiss the ViewController on `.touchUpInside` calling `dismiss()`

If you want, you can have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/Taopath/CardViewController), in which I have a sample project that exhibits this behaviour. That way you can build your own totally customisable cards.

Comment: Your `CardViewController` will also need `let swipeThreshold: CGFloat = 200` and `var viewTranslation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`